# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when using scipy.integrate.quad

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, vectorization, quad

I'm trying to obtain the signal to noise ratio of two variables I have cross-correlated. This involves using scipy.integrate.quad

In short, I've got two functions: an integrand and the integral function.

The integrand takes four inputs: one array and three scalars.

This integrand function works fine: it swallows the array and spits out another.

I then vectorize the integrand using numpy.vectorize.

I then call scipy.integrate.quad in the following way

```
integral, integrall_err = quad(lambda array: integrand(array, scalar, scalar, scalar), 0, array).
```

Then I vectorize the integral as well. When I try and perform it on the actual values I have, it just returns me

```
'TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars'.
```

Here's the code:

```
def ISNR(ell, var, NFRB):     
   
    ad = CL_tauvals + NL_tauvals
    bd = CL_disvals + NFRB
    cd = CL_dtauvals*CL_dtauvals

    res = ell*((CL_dtauvals**2)/(ad*bd + cd))

    return res #dimensionless

ISNR = np.vectorize(ISNR)

test_val = ISNR(1, 300, 4000)


def SNR(ell, var, NFRB, FoV):    
    Integrand = lambda ell: ISNR(ell, var, NFRB)
    snr = quad(Integrand, 0, 100)
    prefactors = np.sqrt(4*np.pi*FoV)
    return prefactors*np.sqrt(snr)

SNR = np.vectorize(SNR)

SNR_test = SNR(l, 100, 100, 100)
```

Note that l is an array of 100 values I've defined using np.logspace. The error message I get is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-31c52985c5c2> in <module>
     22 SNR = np.vectorize(SNR)
     23 
---> 24 SNR_test = SNR(l, 100, 100, 100)

/Software/users/modules/7/software/anaconda3/2020.07/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2089             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
   2090 
-> 2091         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
   2092 
   2093     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):

/Software/users/modules/7/software/anaconda3/2020.07/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
   2159             res = func()
   2160         else:
-> 2161             ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
   2162 
   2163             # Convert args to object arrays first

/Software/users/modules/7/software/anaconda3/2020.07/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args)
   2119 
   2120             inputs = [arg.flat[0] for arg in args]
-> 2121             outputs = func(*inputs)
   2122 
   2123             # Performance note: profiling indicates that -- for simple

<ipython-input-28-31c52985c5c2> in SNR(ell, var, NFRB, FoV)
     16 def SNR(ell, var, NFRB, FoV):
     17     Integrand = lambda ell: ISNR(ell, var, NFRB)
---> 18     snr = quad(Integrand, 0, 100)
     19     prefactors = np.sqrt(4*np.pi*FoV)
     20     return prefactors*np.sqrt(snr)

/Software/users/modules/7/software/anaconda3/2020.07/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    349 
    350     if weight is None:
--> 351         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
    352                        points)
    353     else:

/Software/users/modules/7/software/anaconda3/2020.07/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    461     if points is None:
    462         if infbounds == 0:
--> 463             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    464         else:
    465             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on and/or how to solve this? I've successfully done integrals of the exact same type with some other code recently and the main difference is just that three scalars are taken as inputs alongside the array and just called by the integrand (which works) within the function. I really don't understand why it's trying to convert the array into a scalar: I just want the integral evaluated at each input value.

Some of the solutions I've found tell me to vectorize and use lambda for the variable I'm integrating with... that's exactly what I've done. The other solutions I've found are just not that relevant to what I'm trying to do. If anyone has any tips, I'd be more than grateful.

Comment: My guess is that `Integrand` is not returning the scalar value that `quad` expects.

Comment: There are undefined variables like `CL_tauvals` that keep me from replicating your run.

Comment: Look at `test_val`.  That should be scalar or single value array.  `ISNR`

Comment: What's the `ell` argument ot ``SNR` supposed to be doing (scalar or otherwise)?  There is an `ell` argument to the lambda, but that's provided by `quad`.  You aren't paying close attention to details in this code.

Comment: ah sorry: I probably should have included my definition of the input array for my code as it's quite straightforward. I just did 'import numpy as np' and  'l = np.logspace(np.log10(2), np.log10(5000), num = 100)'. All the terms ending in 'vals' are arrays that I have imported from another Jupyter notebook which required installing a specialist cosmological package so I'm not sure it will be of much use for a test run. For what it's worth though, I just checked and all have length 100 and are numpy arrays.

Comment: - The SNR takes an 'l' array and three scalars as inputs
- Then the l array and two of these inputs are taken as arguments by the integrand
- Quad is then meant to integrate that integrant between 0 and 'l' - in the code above, I put 100 as I was testing it out: the error message is exactly the same though

I'll look at this again after I get some sleep and try to modify based on your comment about the paying attention to the argument provided by quad. Thanks for the feedback! I hope this really is something minor.

Comment: Ok, I just spotted a possible bug in the code I posted above where I was trying to add an array to a scalar - fixed it and then got a different error: TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len(). I'll either modify this post tomorrow or make a new one. Sorry for the avoidable confusion!

Comment: The bounds of a `quad` also must be scalars.  This has bitten people who have tried to evaluate `quad` over different ranges.  The `float has no len` comes from trying to use a single value as though it where a list or array.

Comment: It might be less buggy if you use iteration or list comprehension in place of `vectorize`.  `vectorize` does not have any speed advantages, and has a number of gotchas if you don't read its docs carefullly.

Comment: @hpaulj alright so I've found a solution to the problem - it's slightly crude but it gives me what I need. I just evaluate the integrand at each point, calculate the step of the l-array and then find the cumulative sum of the products of the integrand and step array using the accumulate function from the itertools package. Basically, I'm just doing the discrete version of the integral - it's not for a groundbreaking research paper or PhD thesis so it should be sufficient. Thanks for your help!