# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars during quadrature

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, quad

I'm trying to code the Heston Model in Python. In my final stages, I have to integrate a bunch of integrands. The problem is arising in these lines.

`integrands_list_1` and `integrands_list_2` are lists of `lambda` functions of variable `phi`, I have to integrate these functions to get my final result. When I pass a `df` of a single row I get the desired result however the problem arises when I try to pass a `df` with multiple rows.

In this version of code, I created a list of functions and used a loop to iterate through these functions and then integrate them, however, I get the `TypeError` as stated in the heading.

The error occurs in the `P1` line where I get the error as mentioned earlier.

```py
for integrand1, integrand2 in zip(integrands_list_1, integrands_list_2):
        P1 = 0.5 + (1/np.pi) * quad(integrand1, 0, 100)[0]
        P2 = 0.5 + (1/np.pi) * quad(integrand2, 0, 100)[0]
        results.append((P1, P2))
```

An example df is as follows:

| [QUOTE_DATE] | [UNDERLYING_LAST] | [EXPIRE_DATE] | [STRIKE] | [DTE] | [C_LAST] | [DTB3] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 | 4305.46 | 2022-03-09 | 4000 | 8.0 | 379.71 | 0.0032 |
| 2022-03-01 | 4305.46 | 2022-03-09 | 4050 | 8.0 | 325.41 | 0.0032 |
| 2022-03-01 | 4305.46 | 2022-03-09 | 4140 | 8.0 | 171.22 | 0.0032 |
| 2022-03-01 | 4305.46 | 2022-03-09 | 4150 | 8.0 | 168.82 | 0.0032 |

The Full Error Message:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[24], line 1
----> 1 df_8['Heston Initial'] = Heston_Model.heston_price(df_8, v_0, theta, sigma, rho, kappa)

 File ~/Desktop/Python/BS option pricing/Heston_Model.py:103, in heston_price(df, v_0, theta, sigma, rho, kappa)
    101 print(type(integrand1))
    102 print(integrand1)
--> 103 P1 = 0.5 + (1/np.pi) * quad(integrand1, 0, 100)[0]
    104 P2 = 0.5 + (1/np.pi) * quad(integrand2, 0, 100)[0]
    105 results.append((P1, P2))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Heston Price and Integrand Functions:

```py
def heston_price(df, v_0, theta, sigma, rho, kappa):
    
    St = df['[UNDERLYING_LAST]']
    K = df['[STRIKE]']
    r = df['[DTB3]']
    t = df['[DTE]'] / 252  # Assuming [DTE] is in days

    ### Looping into List
    integrands_list_1 = []
    integrands_list_2 = []

    results = []
    
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        
        phi_values = np.linspace(1, 100, 1000)
        
        integrands = heston_integrand(phi_values, df, v_0, theta, sigma, rho, kappa)
        integrands_list_1.append(integrands[0])
        integrands_list_2.append(integrands[1])

    for integrand1, integrand2 in zip(integrands_list_1, integrands_list_2):
        print(type(integrand1))
        print(integrand1)
        P1 = 0.5 + (1/np.pi) * quad(integrand1, 0, 100)[0]
        P2 = 0.5 + (1/np.pi) * quad(integrand2, 0, 100)[0]
        results.append((P1, P2))

    
    C = St * P1 - K * np.exp(-r*t) * P2
    
    return C

def heston_integrand(phi,df, v_0, theta, sigma, rho, kappa):
    St = df['[UNDERLYING_LAST]']
    K = df['[STRIKE]']
    r = df['[DTB3]']
    t = df['[DTE]'] / 252
    
    integrand1 = lambda phi: np.real(np.exp(-1j * phi * np.log(K)) * 
                        heston_char(St, v_0, t, r, kappa * theta, 0.5, kappa - rho * sigma, rho, sigma, phi) / (1j * phi))
    
    integrand2 = lambda phi: np.real(np.exp(-1j * phi * np.log(K)) * 
                        heston_char(St, v_0, t, r, kappa * theta, -0.5, kappa, rho, sigma, phi) / (1j * phi))

    return integrand1, integrand2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide an example for the functions, we don't know what `integrand1` looks like. And you mention using a pandas DataFrame, but what here is a pandas DataFrame? Also, please include the full error message.

Comment: When I print integrand1, I get the following: 
<function heston_integrand.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x12db740e0>

A Pandas DataFrame here would be the inputs required to calculate the price of a Call Option through the Heston Model.

The Full Error Message? It would exceed the character limit. 

Again, apologies if I'm not fully able to answer the questions, this is a bit new to me.

Comment: But where in your example is the pandas DataFrame? And for the error message, just show the last couple of parts of the traceback to show where the error is and what was called leading up to that error.

Comment: Edit your question to include the full error message with traceback.  Do not attempt to post the error or code in a comment.  Are you sure `integrand1` returns a scalar value? `quad` is a scalar integrator.

Comment: Example DF, Full Error Message, and Functions have been added in the question. 

@hpaulj `integrand1` is a lambda function and calling said function with an argument is a `numpy.ndarray`. However, the code seems to work when it's only a df with one row. Hence the confusion.

Comment: Related, although without accepted answer: - [TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when I try to use scipy.integrate.quad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76591221/12846804) 
- [TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when using scipy.integrate.quad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70399121/12846804). Looks like a popular question without a definitive answer so far

Comment: what's the shape of that array?  when the df has just one row, and when more?

Comment: Does `heston_char` produce an array or series with as many values as there are rows in the dataframe?

Comment: @hpaulj 
1. When df has one row, the dimension is `(1,)`; when the df has multiple rows, the dimension is `( nrows of df, )`.
2. `heston_char` returns a Series corresponding to the number of rows.

Comment: `quad` won't be happy with anything but a `(1,)`.

Comment: @hpaulj I tried to use a `for loop` to get a `(1, )` and then use `quad`, which didn't work. 
Is there any way I convert an `(n, )` to n number of `(1, )`?